# generate JSON with PHP with values from MySql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require("Connection.php");

    $ses = $_SESSION['user'];
    echo "$ses";
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT categoryName FROM Categories WHERE ID_User = (SELECT ID_User from Users WHERE Email='$ses')");
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->fetchAll();

    print '<select id="incomeCat">';
    foreach ($result as $row) {
    print '<option value="'.$row['categoryName'].'">'.$row['categoryName'].'</option>';
        $sql2=$conn->prepare("SELECT Sum FROM Operations WHERE Type='Income' AND categoryName = '$row'  AND CURRENT_DATE-Date < 30 AND ID_User = (SELECT ID_User FROM Users WHERE Email = '$ses')");
        $sql2->execute();
        $result2 = $sql2->fetchColumn();
        echo json_encode($result2);
    }
    print '</select>';
    echo json_encode($result);                                                         
?>
```

I try to generate da JSON report with some data from MySQL with PDO connection (Connection.php works perfectly). I need to make some statistics like: for each category in my database, to sum up each income and expense.
My database tables are `Categories(categoryName, ID_User, Type)`, where type is 'income'/'expense' and `Users(ID_User, Email, password, BirthDate, Location)`.
I've already found other posts on stackoverflow and other sites but they use constant values, not retrieved from DB. I have to mention that the last echo, `echo json_encode($result);` works, and it displays the result like `[{"categoryName":"Banane","0":"Banane"},{"categoryName":"Carti","0":"Carti"},{"categoryName":"Salariu","0":"Salariu"},{"categoryName":"Bursa","0":"Bursa"},{"categoryName":"Loto","0":"Loto"}]` but i need to add also the sum of each category, that "0" I have no idea where it comes from also.
I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what are you actually asking. The code you've provided won't output valid JSON to screen.

Comment: Like I said , I am trying to generate a JSON report using data from my database , in my case I want to generate the sums for those  categories  like the vectors in here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Okay, so problem 1. You can't have HTML and JSON mixed, that would be invalid JSON. Problem 2, you can't just echo json_encode multiple times, again, this causes invalid JSON, You need to product your entire object array and then json_encode it and only it, once.